# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. NewListItems is where the problem lies. cant seem to tackle it though

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

```
//App.js file

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});


const itemsSchema = {
  name:String,
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item" , itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item ({
  name: "Welcome to your toDolist!",
});
const item2 = new Item ({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new item",
});
const item3 = new Item ({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item",
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];


const listSchema = {
  name:String,
  item:[itemsSchema],
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);



app.get("/", function(req, res) {





  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){

    if(foundItems.length === 0 ){
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){

      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else{
        console.log("Successfully saved default items to database.");
      }

      });

      res.redirect("/");

    } else {

        res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});

    }

  });

});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req,res){

const customListName = req.params.customListName;

List.findOne({name:customListName}, function(err, foundList){
if(!err){
  if(!foundList){
    // Create a new listTitle
    const list = new List({
      name: customListName,
      items: defaultItems,
    });



    list.save();
    res.redirect("/" + customListName);
  } else{
  // Show the existing listTitle
  res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
  }
}

});

});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

const item = new Item ({
  name:itemName
});


if(listName=== "Today"){
  item.save();
  res.redirect("/");
} else{
  List.findOne({name:listName} , function(err,foundList){
    foundList.items.push(item);
    foundList.save();
    res.redirect("/" + listName);
  });
}




});



app.post("/delete" , function(req,res){

const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId,function(err){
  if(!err){
    console.log("Successfully deleted the item");
    res.redirect("/");
  }

});

});

app.get("/work", function(req,res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

// List.ejs file

```
<%- include("header") -%>

<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
</div>

<div class="box">


  <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

  <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value=<%=item._id %> onChange="this.form.submit()">
      <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
    </div>

  </form>


  <% }); %>


  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
  </form>
</div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

CODE ENDS HERE

Error paragraph continued

at eval (eval at compile (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12), :13:21)
    at returnedFn (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/app.js:95:7
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4876:16
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4876:16
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4899:21
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4380:11
    at /Users/rohandahima/Desktop/todolist-v2-starting-files/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

Comment: at your `app.get("/work", ...)` `res.render` I don't see where your `workItems` is defined

Comment: @richytong getting the same error even when i comment that code out.